# Spring boot multi project with gradle generates the same jar

Tags: spring, kotlin, gradle

I'm new to gradle and I'm having trouble generating multiple jars with spring boot.
I generate two different builds, but when I run build A or build B, both are A

My project has the following structure:

```
root
├── facade
     ├─── rest-api
     └─── web-api

├── dependencies
     ├─── services
     ├─── entities
     └─── ...

├── settings.gradle
└── build.gradle
```

My intention is to have a mono repo of micro services. The micro services I will generate are the web api and rest api modules of the facade directory. These modules have dependencies of the module called dependencies as its name indicates.

As I described before, when I run the web api module, it's like I'm running rest api, even asking for its dependencies.

My **settings.gradle**:

```
rootProject.name = "root"

include ":root:facade:rest-api"
include ":root:facade:web-api"



include ":root:dependencies:entities"
include ":root:dependencies:services"
...
```

And my **build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
    ext.spring_boot_version = '2.2.2.RELEASE'
    ext.jjwt_version = '0.10.6'
    ext.klockVersion = "1.7.3"
    ext.queryDslVersion = '4.1.4'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$spring_boot_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-noarg:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

group 'org.com'
version '0.1.0'


def javaProjects() {
    return subprojects.findAll { new File(it.projectDir, "src").exists() }
}

subprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    configure(javaProjects()) {
        apply plugin: "java"
        apply plugin: "java-library"
        apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm"
        apply plugin: 'kotlin'
        apply plugin: "kotlin-spring"
        apply plugin: "kotlin-jpa"
        apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
        apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
        compileKotlin {
            kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
        compileTestKotlin {
            kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }


        dependencies {
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
            implementation "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:$jjwt_version"
            implementation "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:$jjwt_version"
            implementation "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:$jjwt_version"
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"

            implementation "com.soywiz.korlibs.klock:klock-jvm:1.7.3"
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect"

            implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
            implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
            implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
            implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")

            implementation "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.3"

            implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin'

            implementation "khttp:khttp:1.0.0"

            testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
                exclude module: 'junit'
                exclude module: 'mockito-core'
            }

            testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.5.2')
            testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine")
            testImplementation('com.ninja-squad:springmockk:2.0.0')
        }

        allOpen {
            annotation("javax.persistence.Entity")
            annotation("javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass")
            annotation("javax.persistence.Embeddable")
        }
    }
}

project(":root:dependencies:services") {
    bootJar {
        enabled = false
    }
    jar {
        enabled = true
    }
}
project(":root:dependencies:entities") {
    bootJar {
        enabled = false
    }
    jar {
        enabled = true
    }
}

...
```

I feel that I must have something wrong with the build.gradle, but I don't understand what.

I also have omitted the build.gradle files of the modules rest api and web api since I only have the dependencies and I have not considered it relevant.

I had previously worked with maven and followed this architecture. I don't know if gradle is the right thing to do, so I'm open to any advice you can give me.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: How do you run your modules?

Comment: `include ":root:facade:rest-api"` This is not how to include a subproject. Drop the `:root` part unless you are doing something else like `project(':root:facade:rest-api').projectDir=...`

Comment: @BjørnVester I run in root with gradle wrapper using  `bash gradlew build`

Comment: @smac89 I tried to remove :root from the settings file and it seems that I don't need the conditional in configure inside the bundle.gradle file anymore. I don't quite understand what difference there was between the two path configurations in the settings file that caused such a change, would you mind explaining it to me?

Still the project cannot compile due to an error. The error says: 
`Main class name has not been configured and it could not be resolved`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, the correct way to include subprojects is to replace the path to the subproject with `:` i.e. if the subproject is in (from the root project) sub/project1, then the correct way to include it is:

```
include ':sub:project1'
```

Now as for your other question in the comments regarding:

> *Main class name has not been configured and it could not be resolved*

You can simply do:

```
mainClassName = 'full.cannonical.name.of.MainClass'
```

If all the projects have a main class, then you need to do this in each project's build.gradle